# appium inspector not load application

Tags: testing, appium, appium-android

I'm trying to Android mobile testing, but Appium server give an error.

In AVD, app starting, Inspector starting but epmty.
[image: inspector loading]

Server side error logs:
[image: server log 1]

[image: server log 2]

My capabilities:

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:platformVersion": "8.1",
  "appium:appPackage": "com.a101.sos.bs",
  "appium:appActivity": "com.a101.sos.bs.SplashScreenActivity",
  "appium:deviceName": "appTest",
  "appium:automationName": "Appium",
  "appium:udid": "emulator-5554"
}
```

I'm using latest version of Appium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised in our app we are not allow take screenshot, and screen recording, because of this Appium Inspector can't load our app. Now I'm using screen recording enabled version, and it's work. = )